# WebSession in WebFlux session creation

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

What does webSession.getId()  do, does it always create a new session. Or it just returns an existing session id if session already exist.

I dont see any clear documentation in spring as well. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in the `InMemoryWebSessionStore` class, it just returns `this.id`:

```
public String getId() {
  return (String)this.id.get();
}
```

Here is the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebSession.html#getId--)